# Firefox SDK PageWorker: Addon is not defined

Tags: javascript, sdk, websocket, firefox-addon, worker

i have no clue, why this Problem occurs, i followed this guide: [MDN Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-worker#Scripting_trusted_page_content)

But still get the Error:

```
JavaScript error: resource://jid1-rcm3stktbkcg3q-at-jetpack/ff/data/websockethtmlscript.js, line 23: ReferenceError: addon is not defined
```

Messages FROM the websocket are received and everything is fine, but i cannot send messages TO the server as the websocket.html doesn't "hear" me because it cannot apply the port listener. But i do not see the problem why.
Does anybody see my mistake?

Here is the PageWorker initiation part in my "**main.js**"

```
var buttons = require('sdk/ui/button/action'); 
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
var pageWorker = require("sdk/page-worker");
var self = require("sdk/self");
var settings = require("sdk/simple-prefs");
var activeTABURL = "no";
var about_config = require("sdk/preferences/service");
about_config.set("network.websocket.allowInsecureFromHTTPS", true);

//create page-worker to load trusted content
var pw = pageWorker.Page({
    contentURL: './websocket.html'
});

pw.port.on('loaded', function() { 
//donothing 
});

//add portlistener to receive messages from websocketserver
pw.port.on('eyeTrackerData', function(message) {
    if (currentPort != null) {
        //currentport is the worker port for the pageMod
        //here, the messages from the websocketserver are forwarded
        currentPort.emit('eyeTrackerData',message); 
    }
});
```

and the **websocket.html**:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="websockethtmlscript.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

the **websockethtmlscript.js**:

```
websocket.onmessage = function(evt) { onMessage(evt); };
websocket.onopen = function(evt) { websocket.send("HI.") };
websocket.onerror = function(evt) { onError(evt); };

function disconnect(){
    websocket.close();
}

function onError(evt) {
    console.log("An error occured in the websocket.html - is the WebSocket Server running?");
}

function onMessage(evt) {
    addon.port.emit('eyeTrackerData',evt.data);       
}

function sendMessage(message){
    //addon.port.emit('message','message_sent');
    websocket.send(message);
}
//add port listener to send messages to the websocketserver
addon.port.on("toEyetracker",function (message){
    console.log("websocket.html sending to websocketserver: "+message);
    sendMessage(message);
});
```

So **addon.port.emit** works, while **addon.port.on** does *not*. But why?

Thank you (at least for reading) :)

Comment: Any reason not to use `contentScriptFile` instead of a `<script>` tag?

Comment: Mainly, because the MDN API Guide says so:
   
`in the "main.js" file: remove the contentScriptFile option in the Page()    constructor.`

Comment: "To interact with trusted content you *don't need* to use content scripts".  You can still use them. Anyway, it might be a timing issue, since you use your `port.on` in a top level scope while the `port.emit` is used in callbacks. Maybe try registering it later .

Answer (score 0):

it *was* the timing problem. this is my `websockethtmlscript.js` now:

```
var websocket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:6777');
websocket.onmessage = function(evt) { messageReceived(evt); };
websocket.onopen = function(evt) { conReady(); };
websocket.onerror = function(evt) { onError(evt); };

function disconnect(){
    websocket.close();
}

function onError(evt) {
    console.log("An error occured in the websocket.html - is the WebSocket Server running?");
}

function messageReceived(evt) { 

    addon.port.emit('eyeTrackerData',evt.data);       

}

function conReady() {
    console.log("connection established");
    console.log("adding port listener");
    addon.port.on("toEyetracker",function (message){
        console.log("websocket.html sending to websocketserver: "+message);
        try{
            sendMessage(message);
        } catch (err){
            console.log("Error in Websocket Page-Worker: "+err.name);
        }
    });
    addon.port.emit('conReady',"ready");
    websocket.send("HI.");
}

function sendMessage(message){
    websocket.send(message);
}
```

so i added a function that is called when the connection is established - not till then the port listener is added and tells the main.js that everything went fine. -

another thing i altered was the pageworker constructor itself:

```
var pw = pageWorker.Page({

});
```

it is only initialized at the beginning.

in my page-mod onAttach-callback i then added

```
pw.contentURL = './websocket.html';
```

i didn't know that was possible earlier.

so now it runs with no errors. thanks to the8472 for pointing out the timing issue. *sometimes you just look at the wrong end for errors* :)